# Why does go's compiler "gc" use a different calling convention than C?

Tags: go, cdecl

C uses the cdecl, which I've looked into and called with from assembly. It feels well enough, so why break the compatibility? Why was another convention needed?

Comment: Go allows multiple return values and gc uses segmented stacks. I'm not entirely sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if these features are related to the calling conventions. Afaik, the only way to return multiple values with cdecl is to return a pointer to a structure.

Comment: C does not use the cdecl calling convention. Some implementations use it, and some use other calling conventions.

Comment: AFAIK the Google implementation of Go uses a calling convention that is equal to that of C except in the places where C can't express the concept Go uses (such as when there are multiple return values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there's no advantage in having the same calling convention. Go code and C code cannot call each other directly even when the calling convention would be the same because Go uses split stacks.

OTOH, it makes sense in gccgo, as gcc supports C split stacks for some architectures. And, IIRC, there the calling convention is because of that compatible. (More [details here](http://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo#C_Interoperability).)

Disclaimer: I didn't ever actually used gccgo.